# How do I add a custom watch step to webpack in a vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm surprised I can't find an example of this, but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places.

I have a pretty standard Vue 2 app created with vue-cli (that is, the way to start the dev server is `vue-cli-service serve`). Webpack is configured in the `vue.config.js` file.

I want to run a script every time a particular file changes. That is, when `/path/to/file/x.js` changes, first run `./my-script.sh` before doing the regular webpack compilation.

I'm hoping there is a built in way to do this. I'm starting to wonder if I need to create a webpack plugin, though.

(Also, I hope this doesn't complicate it but I'll be converting to Vue 3 sometime this year.)

Comment: Are you using npm for package management?

Comment: Yes, I am......